# mysql replication between three nodes ( master master replication and one directional slave)

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysql-5.7

I have three mySQL servers 5.7 running on centos 7, lets call them A, B , C.

```
A is master of B
B is master of A
A is master of C
```

if i make a change in the database from A it updates B and C.

if i make a change in the database from B it only updates A and **not** C. also A position doesn't change so C won't update.

I'm new in replication so i'm asking here to verify what i'm doing wrong.

1.Is this design is flawed and I need to make server B master of C as well  ? 
I saw i can make masters on different channels

2.How come Server A position doesn't change when he updates the data from B (When i sent update from B).

my intention is to replicate data between all servers while having another master in case of failover and a slave that i can use mostly for reading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable [log_slave_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) on the server that's acting as the master for C, in your case server A (though more usually server B as in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this variable exist.